# Validar somas de tabela dinâmica em JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, html5

Tenho uma dúvida em validar somas de tabelas dinâmicas.
Tenho 2 inputs um com o valor com iva e outro do valor sem iva.
Tenho uma tabela dinâmica em que insiro os períodos de facturação.
Ao colocar o valor total com iva ele tem de somar todos os valores com iva introduzidos na tabela. Apenas consigo fazer isso com os valores com iva.
como faço para os valores sem iva? Não sei como fazer.
Obrigada!

```js
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
 function addRow(tableID) {
  var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
  var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
  var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
  for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
   var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
   newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
   //alert(newcell.childNodes);
   switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
    case "text":
     newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
     break;
    case "checkbox":
     newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
     break;
    case "select-one":
     newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
     break;
   }
  }
 }
 function deleteRow(tableID) {
  try {
   var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
   var rowCount = table.rows.length;
   for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
    var row = table.rows[i];
    var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
    if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
     if(rowCount <= 1) {
      alert("Não é possível apagar todas as linhas da tabela.");
      break;
     }
     table.deleteRow(i);
     rowCount--;
     i--;
    }
   }
  }catch(e) {
   alert(e);
  }
 }
 var quant_civa = document.getElementsByName("valor_afaturar_civa[]");
 var quant_siva = document.getElementsByName("valor_afaturar_siva[]");
 var teste = [];
 teste = dataString.split(",");
 function verifica(){
  var designacao_prest_serv = f.designacao_prest_serv.value;
  var fk_obra = f.fk_obra.value;
  var valor_total_civa = f.valor_total_civa.value;
  var valor_total_siva = f.valor_total_siva.value;
  var fk_subcontratado = f.fk_subcontratado.value;
  
  if (designacao_prest_serv == '' || designacao_prest_serv == ' '){
   alert ("Preencha a designação da prestação de serviços");
   designacao_prest_serv.focus();
   return false;
  }
  if (fk_subcontratado == '0') {
   alert ("Selecione um subcontratado");
   return false;
  }
  else{
   var soma_civa = 0;
   for (var i=0; i<quant_civa.length; i++){
    teste[i] = parseFloat(quant_civa[i].value);
    soma_civa += parseFloat(teste[i])   
   }
   if (soma_civa == valor_total_civa){
    return true;    
   }
   else{
    alert('A soma dos períodos de faturação não corresponde ao valor da Prestação de Serviços');
    return false;
   }

  }
 }
 function habilitar(){
 if(document.getElementById('obra').checked){
  document.getElementById('fk_obra').disabled = false;
  document.getElementById('fk_obra').value = 'obra';

 } else{
  document.getElementById('fk_obra').disabled = true;
  document.getElementById('fk_obra').value = '';

 }
}
</script>
```

```html
<?php  $sql = "SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'adicionais_contrato'";
  $resultado = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
  $linha = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);
  $idd = $linha['Auto_increment']; ?>
<h2>Criar Prestação de Serviços - Subcontratados</h2>
<form name="f" action="enviar_criar_adicional.php?id=<?php echo $idd; ?>" method="post" >
 <strong>Designa&ccedil;&atilde;o da prestação de serviços:</strong><br />
 <input id="designacao_prest_serv" type="text" size="100" name="designacao_prest_serv" maxlength="150" required/></br></br>
 <strong>Subcontratados:</strong>
 <select name="fk_subcontratado" id="fk_subcontratado">
 <option value="0">Selecione...</option>
 <?php $query_subcontratado = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM subcontratados ORDER BY nome ASC");
 while($subcontratado = mysqli_fetch_array($query_subcontratado)) { ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $subcontratado['id'] ?>" title="<?php echo $subcontratado['nome'] ?>"><?php echo $subcontratado['nome']; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
 </select><br><br>
 <label style="cursor: pointer;">
 <input type="radio" name="custos" id="custos_gerais" value="custos_gerais" onclick="habilitar();" checked  /> <strong>Custos Gerais</strong></label>
 <label style="cursor: pointer;">
 <input type="radio" name="custos" id="obra" value="obra" onclick="habilitar();"/> <strong>Obra</strong></label><br>
 <select name="fk_obra" id="fk_obra" disabled required>
  <option value="0">Selecione a obra...</option>
  <?php $query_prefixo = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM prefixos ");
  while($prefixo = mysqli_fetch_array($query_prefixo)) { 
   $query_obra = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM obras WHERE fk_prefixo=".$prefixo['id']." ORDER BY abrev_ano ASC, num_sequencial ASC");
   while($obra = mysqli_fetch_array($query_obra)) { 
    $id_obra = $obra['id'];?>
    <option value="<?php echo $obra['id'] ?>" title="<?php echo $obra['designacao'] ?>"><?php echo "O".$prefixo['tipo'].$obra['abrev_ano'].".".$obra['num_sequencial'].".".$obra['abrev_designacao']; ?></option>
   <?php
   }
  } ?>
 </select>
 <?php $data_abertura = date('Y-m-d'); ?>
 <br><br><strong>Data de abertura: </strong><?php echo $data_abertura ?><br /><br />
 <strong>Valor Total da Prestação de Serviços<br> Com IVA: </strong><input type="text" name="valor_total_civa" id="valor_total_civa" required/>
 <strong>Sem IVA: </strong><input type="text" name="valor_total_siva" id="valor_total_siva" required/><br /><br />
 <strong>Periodos de Fatura&ccedil;&atilde;o:</strong><br>
 <INPUT type="button" value="Adicionar linha" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />
 <INPUT type="button" value="Apagar Linha" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />
 <TABLE id="dataTable">
  <TR>
   <TD width="20px;"><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk"/></TD>
   <TD width="100px;"><INPUT type="date" min="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>" id="data_afaturar" name="data_afaturar[]" required/></TD>
   <TD>Com IVA:<input type="text" name="valor_afaturar_civa[]" id="valor_afaturar_civa[]" value="0.00" required>€</TD>
   <TD>Sem IVA:<input type="text" name="valor_afaturar_siva[]" id="valor_afaturar_siva[]" value="0.00" required>€</TD>
  </TR>
 </TABLE>
 <p><input type="submit" onClick="return verifica()" value="Criar Prestação de Serviços"></p></br>
</form>
```

Comment: Eu estou um bocado confuso com o teu código. Principalmente porque está dividido em partes e na última parece que aparecem valores e objetos do nada. Será que podias mostrar o código com que funcione com os valores com IVA? Assim seria mais fácil trabalhar com os sem IVA.

Comment: Por que não consegues fazer com valores sem iva? Qual erro está acontecendo?

Comment: Já coloquei todo o código... Apenas não sei fazer para o outro campo Sem IVA..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Experimenta adicionar a seguinte função `CalcularValoresSemIVA()`, que calcula o total de todos os elementos com o nome `valor_afaturar_siva[]`, nas tuas funções de adicionar e apagar linhas:

```
function CalcularValoresSemIVA(){
  var TotalValoresSemIVA = 0;
  for(i=0;i<document.getElementsByName("valor_afaturar_siva[]").length;i++){
    TotalValoresSemIVA += eval(document.getElementsByName("valor_afaturar_siva[]")[i].value);
  }
  alert("Total dos valores sem IVA: " + TotalValoresSemIVA + "€");
}
```

**Editado:**

Se queres ter o valor antes de testar as validações simplesmente faz algo deste género:

```
function verifica(){
  /*
    No início da tua função verifica() que é chamada
    ao clicar em "Criar Prestação de Serviços" usas
    o meu código para obteres a variável com o valor
  */
  var TotalValoresSemIVA = 0;
  for(i=0;i<document.getElementsByName("valor_afaturar_siva[]").length;i++){
    TotalValoresSemIVA += eval(document.getElementsByName("valor_afaturar_siva[]")[i].value);
  }
  /*
    Depois fazes o que quiseres com a variável
    TotalValoresSemIVA nas validações abaixo
  */
}
```

**Último código:**

```js
var Total = 0;
for(i=1; i<9; i++) {
  var NumAleatorio = Math.random().toFixed(2);
  document.write("Número " + i + " = " + NumAleatorio + "<br>");
  Total += eval(NumAleatorio);
}
document.write("Total sem toFixed(2) = " + Total);
document.write("<br>");
document.write("Total com toFixed(2) = " + Total.toFixed(2));
```

Comment: Onde chamo essa função?

Comment: Não respondi logo porque fui almoçar. Adiciona/declara esta função e chama-a por exemplo, no início da tua função `addRow(tableID)` e no fim da `deleteRow(tableID)`. Depois é só modificares/removeres a linha de códico com o  `alert(...);` e fazeres o que quiseres com a variável `TotalValoresSemIVA`.

Comment: Mas e se for apenas um período de facturação, não vou adicionar nem apagar linha, logo não vou chamar a função... já tentei colocar dentro do 
if (soma_civa == valor_total_civa){
 CalcularValoresSemIVA();    
}

Pois só quando tiver esses valores iguais é que posso prosseguir.

Comment: Um "período de facturação"? Não sem bem o que queres dizer com isso. Quando é que queres que atualize o valor, que esteja a atualizar de x em x tempo, quando um certo botão é clicado, em algum evento ou quando um dos valores muda? Eu posso te explicar praticamente qualquer uma das opções, só não sei é bem qual é que tu queres.

Comment: Quero que quando clique em "Criar Prestação de Serviços" ele valide os valores. somar todos os valores dos periodos de faturação (tabela dinamica) e confirmar se é igual ao colocado no input. Isto tanto para os valores Com IVA como para os valores Sem IVA

Comment: Verifica o código que eu adicionei/editei à minha resposta.

Comment: Obrigada e desculpa o incómodo =) Funcionou!

Comment: Não faz mal, feliz por ajudar. :)

Comment: Olá, notei que agora tenho um problema com as casas decimais. Por exemplo quando somo 2.02 + 2.02+2.02 o total dá 6.0600000000000005. Queria que ele apenas utilizasse até 2 casas decimais. Já tentei com o eval(document.getElementsByName("valor_afaturar_siva[]")[i].value).toFixed(2); mas o valor que dá da soma é 02.022.022.02€. Como faço?

Comment: @JoanaAguiar, vê o último código na minha resposta. O `toFixed(2)` parece-me estar a funcionar [bem](http://i.imgur.com/40TWZ23.png). Tenta aplicá-lo à variável `TotalValoresSemIVA ` no final do ciclo `for`. Usa `toFixed(2)` no resultado da conta.

Comment: Obrigada =) Funcionou!

Comment: @JoanaAguiar: Fixe.